# An issue with CSS animations and JS classList.add

Tags: javascript, css, class, animation, keyframe

I'm writing a private 'framework' of sorts in order to have some basic effects without the need of jQuery.
I've just written some code for fade-ins/outs, and basically what I do is add/remove classes, and check for animation support.

Here's the JavaScript part (please, check mainly the fadeIn, fadeOut properties):

```
var effs = {

    checkSupport: (function() {

        var init = true;
        var supports = false;

        return function(el) {
            if (init) {
                var animationstring = 'animation',
                    keyframeprefix = '',
                    domPrefixes = 'Webkit Moz O ms Khtml'.split(' '),
                    pfx = '';

                if (el.style.animationName !== undefined) {
                    supports = true;
                }

                if (supports === false) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < domPrefixes.length; i++) {
                        if (el.style[domPrefixes[i] + 'AnimationName'] !== undefined) {
                            pfx = domPrefixes[i];
                            animationstring = pfx + 'Animation';
                            keyframeprefix = '-' + pfx.toLowerCase() + '-';
                            supports = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                init = false;
            }
            return supports;
        };

    }()),

    fadeOut: function(el) {
        el.style.opacity = 1;
        if (this.checkSupport(el)) {
            el.classList.remove("fadeIn", "fadeOut");

        //Here comes the annoying timeout!

            setTimeout(function() {
                el.classList.add("fadeOut");
            }, 25);

        } else {
            el.style.opacity = 0;
        }
    },


    fadeIn: function(el) {
        el.style.opacity = 0;
        if (this.checkSupport(el)) {
            el.classList.remove("fadeIn", "fadeOut");
            setTimeout(function() {
                el.classList.add("fadeIn");
            }, 25);
        } else {
            el.style.opacity = 1;
        }
    }

};
```

As you can see, I have had to delay the addition of the animation class, because without that timeout, the animation doesn't show the second time around in Chrome(and other Webkit browsers), when it is called on the same element. It does work in Firefox without the timeout, though.

I also tested this in Midori, and since it's also a Webkit browser, it needs the timeout as well, but with the added annoyance of the delay being even longer than 25ms, for some reason.

Why is this? Is there any other way around that you can think of? I know these methods aren't very compatible with a lot of browsers, but I don't mind the animations not showing in some of them. Thank you.